# Ширина HTML элемента

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, width

Когда указываешь в CSS длину элемента 100%

```
#cont{
width: 100%;
height: 30px;
background-color: red;
}
```

То на деле в браузере остаются небольшие рамки. Как это исправить?

Comment: Убрать маргины и паддинги у `<html>` и `<body>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это потому что у `body` изначально стоит `margin`.

Очень популярная практика - убирать `margin` и `padding` у всех элементов:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding : 0;
}
```

Добавте это в начало файла и все.

Answer (score 0):

Свойство box-sizing. Посмотрите тут http://htmlbook.ru/css/box-sizing

UPD: плюс убрать отступы у родительских элементов.